# Azure service principal to create and log into B2C tenants

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm new to azure and I wanted to perfom some tasks using the azure graph API. I want to create a b2c tenant using a service principal and also log into the b2c tenant to performe some tasks. But I noticed in the custom permission, there is no permission to create a B2C tenant the only permission I found is: `Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2ctenants/read`

Do I have to add the admin rights to the SP to be able to create a b2c tenant with the SP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a service principal to create AAD B2C tenants. To create an AAD B2C tenant, you must use ARM API, not Graph API.
The API endpoint only supports user authentication (user_impersonation permission):

[ARM API create B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/activedirectory/b2c-tenants/create#scopes)

To manage a B2C tenant that has been created, that can be managed with servicePrinicpal using Application Permissions for MS Graph API. When creating the application registration (servicePrincipal), choose "Accounts in this organisation directory" (first) option.

[Get a token to Graph using servicePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)
[AAD B2C Graph API operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations)

Comment: Any chance this is on the roadmap? It would be great to have a full test deployment pipeline, provisioning, testing, deprovisioning, etc

Comment: It’s not, the reason is, we need a user account to make the first global admin account.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT it's a shame, the API does not allow to input a user to be the initial global Admin. How are we supposed to automate the creation of a tenant in IaC?

Comment: The only way is to auth a user account using ROPC, with an account that excludes MFA for just this particular operation.